# Should coprime numbers both be prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Two numbers $a$ and $b$ are coprime if and only if $(a, b) = 1$.

$(4, 5) = 1$, are $4$ and $5$ coprime?

Comment: $n$ and $n+1$ are always coprime.

Comment: The word is [coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers), not comprime.

Comment: If two numbers are both prime, they are always coprime. The reverse isn't true, as there are non-prime pair of numbers that are still coprime (like $4$ and $5$ in your example).

Comment: The question in the title is different from the question in the body. The answer to the former is no, and the answer to the latter is yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two numbers $a$ and $b$ are coprime if ad only if they have no common factor or more generally H.C.F.$(a,b)=1$.

There are many numbers which do not have a common factor between them and they still are coprime. For example $(4,9)$, $(9,25)$ are coprime even when none of the numbers is prime.

In you example too, $4$ is not prime but still the pair $(4,5)$ is of coprime numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Two numbers $a,b$ are coprime $\iff \gcd(a,b)=1$

Thus $\gcd(4,5)=1=\gcd(2^2,5)=1$ As you see 4 doesn't share a prime factor with 5, so they are coprime. Extending this, we know that $a$ and $b$ are coprimes if they don't have prime factors in common.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to the defnition of coprime even though $4$ is not a prime number.

The only common factor between the two numbers is $1$.